# Three.js and KineticJS, save KineticJS layer to THREE.texture

Tags: javascript, html, textures, three.js, kineticjs

My question is pretty much exactly as the title states. I need to somehow convert a KineticJS layer into a ThreeJS texture so that I can apply it to a plane. I'm doing this because I need to utilize KineticJS's text manipulation abilities in my 3D scene.

I'm currently using the line

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture(layer.getCanvas());
```

To convert it to a texture, but that doesn't work at all. How would I go about doing this correctly? Would I need to set up the scene within a stage first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
toDataURL();
```

Then use that image as a texture .

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html

Comment: So in order to load this, would I just make another image element and set its source to the output of that toDataURL method, then convert it to a texture, like in the second post in this example?
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1305